# Got an unexpected keyword argument 'label' while drawing box and whisker plot in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python matplotlib version 1.4.3
When I try to set `label` parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] 
plt.boxplot(data, label=list('abc'))
plt.show()
```

I get error:

`TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`

while `label` is a documented parameter http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the docstring again.  The argument is `labels`.