# TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, ipython

I'm using ipython 3.2.0, and I'm trying to use boxplot. Online documentation and examples suggest that a keyword "labels" should exist, as also stated in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014121/got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-label-while-drawing-box-and-whisker-plot-in) post, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

Was the labels keyword removed? If so, what is the official way to get a legend for a boxplot?

Comment: Can you show us your code? labels should be a keyword for boxplot....

Comment: The problem was that I had matplotlib 1.3.1. I've upgraded to 1.4.3, but am faced with a new problem which is that pylab gives the error "ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg" on startup.

Comment: update: the tk issue was solved with the steps stated here: https://github.com/pism/regional-tools/issues/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `labels` kwarg was added in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643, first shipped with mpl v1.4.0 and is still present [on master](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2953).

Comment: I see. Turns out I have matplotlib 1.3.1. I had incorrectly assumed that upgrading ipython via pip would also update matplotlib. I'm not sure how to update matplotlib separately, but I'll look into it.

Comment: try a pip install --upgrade --user matplotlib

Comment: hmm, but I am getting this error with matplotlib-3.3.4 / python 3.9.1

Answer (score 1):

The solution did not work for me (Python 33 on Windows).
I found another way and leave it here just in case someone else may need it:

1. Uninstall the old version: pip uninstall matplotlib
2. Download the wheel file from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.4.3
3. Run pip install path_to_whl_file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, here is a complete summary:

1. The labels command has been available since 1.4.0 as tcaswell states.
2. "sudo pip install --upgrade ipython" updates only ipython
3. My mistake was assuming that matplotlib was a "dependency" of matplotlib, and that pip would upgrade it as well, similar to apt
4. "sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib" worked, but lead to the error "ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg" when ipython starts.
5. Per the instructions [here](https://github.com/pism/regional-tools/issues/3), removing matplotlib, installing the packages tk and tk-dev, and reinstalling matplotlib, resolved the _tkagg error

Comment: You should almost _never_ do `sudo pip install ...` as it can mess with your system level installed packages.  If you want to use versions of libraries are different than what your distro ships use virtual environments (either venv or conda).

Comment: Well, shoot. this was the recommended solution for updating ipython/matplotlib that i found online. Do you have a reference for how to correctly perform the update, and how to undo any damage? I had tried running apt first but it reported all packages up-to-date, indicating that the official ubuntu repositories still have very old versions of matplotlib/ipython?

Comment: I suggest using anaconda + environments or enthought canopy or venv + pip